# Highcharts - color of the labels for column chart

Tags: highcharts

I have read this: [Changing Color of Data Labels in HighCharts Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886851/changing-color-of-data-labels-in-highcharts-bar-chart)

And some documentation of Highcharts and I still can't get it to work. I have a following visualisation:

[image]

As you can see the data labels are blue. In a box below I can add code to overwrite default values and this is what I have:

```
{
  chart: {},
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      colorByPoint: true
    }
  },
  colors: [
      '#1A73E8',
      '#12B5CB',
      '#E52592',
      '#E8710A',
      '#F9AB00',
      '#9334E6',
      '#7CB342'
  ],
  series: [{
    name: 'Average',
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: '#f4f4f4'
      }
    }
  }]
```

This allows me to change the colours of columns but I can't get the labels to change colour. Surprisingly if I do this:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Average',
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        color: '#f4f4f4',
        fontSize: '16px'
      }
    }
  }]
```

Then the font size takes effect but not the colour. Is it a different syntax or place where I have to do it.

Here is the code of the original query (without the data as the tool hides the data)

```
{
  accessibility: {
    landmarkVerbosity: 'disabled',
    point: {},
  },
  annotations: [],
  chart: {
    animation: false,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
    inverted: false,
    orderStacks: 'none',
    spacingRight: 15.25,
    spacingTop: 24,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'inherit',
      fontSize: '12px',
    },
    type: 'column',
    events: {},
    zoomType: 'xy',
    panning: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    panKey: 'shift',
    resetZoomButton: {
      theme: {
        fill: '#FFF',
        stroke: '#c1c6cc',
        r: 3,
        style: {
          color: '#1A73E8',
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            stroke: '#939ba5',
            fill: '#FFF',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  defs: {
    percentOfPreviousRightArrow: {
      id: 'percent-of-previous-right-arrow',
      tagName: 'marker',
      children: [
        {
          tagName: 'path',
          d: 'M0,3.5L0 10.5 12 10.5 12 13 16 7 12 1 12 3.5z',
        },
      ],
      markerWidth: 16,
      markerHeight: 13,
      refX: 9,
      refY: 7,
    },
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      animation: false,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      connectNulls: true,
      turboThreshold: 5000,
    },
  },
  responsive: {
    rules: [
      {
        condition: {},
        chartOptions: {
          series: [
            {
              type: 'column',
              id: 'average',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
              },
            },
          ],
          xAxis: {
            title: {
              style: {
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                width: '100%',
              },
            },
          },
          yAxis: [
            {
              stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              title: {
                style: {
                  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                  width: '100%',
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        condition: {},
        chartOptions: {
          series: [
            {
              type: 'column',
              id: 'average',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
              },
            },
          ],
          title: {},
          xAxis: {
            title: {
              style: {
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                width: '100%',
              },
            },
            labels: {
              enabled: false,
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
          },
          yAxis: [
            {
              title: {
                style: {
                  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
                  width: '100%',
                },
              },
              stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        condition: {},
        chartOptions: {
          series: [
            {
              type: 'column',
              id: 'average',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
              },
            },
          ],
          title: {},
          xAxis: {
            title: {},
            labels: {
              enabled: false,
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
          },
          yAxis: [
            {
              title: {},
              labels: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              gridLineWidth: 0,
              stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        condition: {},
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  series: [
    {
      color: '#1A73E8',
      data: [],
      dataLabels: {
        crop: false,
        enabled: true,
        overflow: 'none',
        style: {
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          textOutline: 'none',
        },
      },
      events: {},
      id: 'average',
      index: 0,
      legendIndex: 0,
      name: 'Average',
      series: {
        data: [],
        xAxisType: 'category',
        yCategories: [],
        result: {},
        config: {},
        type: 'column',
        id: 'average',
        field: {},
        index: 0,
        isSilhouetted: false,
        legendIndex: 0,
        numberOfSeries: 1,
        numberOfFields: 1,
      },
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1,
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        followPointer: true,
      },
      type: 'column',
      visible: true,
      yAxis: 0,
      zIndex: 0,
      zoneAxis: 'y',
      zones: [],
      stickyTracking: true,
      borderWidth: 0,
      groupPadding: 0.05,
      pointPadding: 0,
      hideStackedChartValueLabels: false,
    },
  ],
  title: {
    text: null,
  },
  tooltip: {
    animation: false,
    backgroundColor: 'var(--vis-color-tooltip-background)',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 4,
    hideDelay: 0,
    outside: true,
    padding: 8,
    shadow: false,
    shape: 'square',
    style: {
      color: 'var(--vis-color-tooltip-text)',
      fontWeight: '400px',
      fontFamily: 'inherit',
    },
    useHTML: true,
  },
  xAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
      second: '%H:%M:%S',
      minute: '%H:%M',
      hour: '%H:%M',
      day: '%b %e',
      week: '%b %e',
      month: '%B',
      year: '%Y',
    },
    gridLineColor: '#e6e6e6',
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    keepOrder: true,
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
      data: [],
      events: {},
      autoRotationLimit: 150,
      style: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        fontSize: '12px',
        color: 'inherit',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      },
      useHTML: true,
    },
    maxPadding: 0.01,
    minPadding: 0.01,
    offset: 0,
    reversed: false,
    startOfWeek: 1,
    tickLength: 0,
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    type: 'category',
    uniqueNames: false,
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      allowDecimals: false,
      dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
        second: '%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%H:%M',
        hour: '%H:%M',
        day: '%b %e',
        week: '%b %e',
        month: '%B',
        year: '%Y',
      },
      endOnTick: false,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      labels: {
        enabled: true,
        events: {},
        style: {
          color: 'inherit',
          fontSize: '12px',
        },
        useHTML: true,
      },
      maxPadding: 0.01,
      opposite: false,
      plotBands: [],
      plotLines: [],
      reversed: false,
      reversedStacks: false,
      softMax: 0,
      softMin: 0,
      stackLabels: {
        allowOverlap: false,
        enabled: false,
        style: {
          color: '#808080',
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          textOutline: 'none',
        },
      },
      startOnTick: false,
      tickPixelInterval: 10,
      title: {
        style: {
          color: 'inherit',
        },
        text: null,
        useHTML: true,
      },
      type: 'linear',
      visible: true,
    },
  ],
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a simplified example based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/su8yqfb9/. As you can see, with the responsive rules commented out, the dataLabels work correctly. This is because the responsive rules disable dataLabels. I am not fully sure if this is the case you described, so could you please replicate your issue in the demo?"

Comment: The response part comes from the vendor, that's how they structure the code. I can only overwrite what's there, which means I can't remove this responsive / rules part. I added a screenshot of what the UI looks like

Comment: I'm araid that the issue you're experiencing might stem from the tool itself, rather than being a problem with Highcharts. However, there are a couple of approaches you could try: Instead of applying the color through the style settings, try setting it directly in the dataLabels. If that doesn't resolve the issue, try setting it within the responsive rules.